# Adding Ruby-on-Rails database records outside of browser requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to capture raw real-time gps data (from gpsd, either NMEA Sentences or JSON records) and place those records into the RoR database. I've got a GEM developed that does the socket processing with gpsd, and sends the received data to callback methods. I also have an initializer in my RoR app that uses that GEM to receive the data, and currently pumps it out to a log file.

What I am missing is the process to place the data into a database record.

I am re-learning RoR from years ago, and believe this is probably a trivial question, But I don't seem to be able to find the answer. Help is appreciated. (Using RoR 6)

Here is the (stripped down) contents of config/initializers/gps.rb.  The final call 'process_raw' needs to dump the data into the database instead of the log file.

```
require 'my_gpsd_client'

DEFAULT_WATCH={"enable":true,"json":true,"nmea":false,"raw":true}
DEFAULT_HOST='127.0.0.1'
DEFAULT_PORT=2947

@gps_logger = Logger.new('log/gps_logfile.log')

Rails.configuration.after_initialize do
  @gps = MyGpsdClient.new(host: DEFAULT_HOST, port: DEFAULT_PORT, watch: DEFAULT_WATCH, verbose: true)
  @gps.on_raw_change { |json| process_raw(json)}

  @gps.start
end

def process_raw ( data)
  @gps_logger.debug "Raw Data: #{data}"
end
```

As requested, the 'structure' of the data. Right now, it's just a string.  From schema.rb...

```
  create_table "raw_data", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "rawdata"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

At this time, I'm just concerned about how to write a record (consisting of a string) to a database from initializers/gps.rb listed above. Once that is working I can parse the raw data to write to other tables with a more meaningful structure.

Also, there is a controllers/gps_message_controller.rb, models/gps_message.rb, and views/gps_messages folder. These were generated by a scaffold simply to display the raw data strings in the database, and are unmodified.

Comment: If you've deployed to Heroku, you can use the scheduler to run rake tasks. You can fetch the data you want in said rake task. Otherwise, you could make cron jobs to run them(I am new to creating cron jobs, not sure if they run your rake tasks or if they perform the task themselves)

Comment: Thanks, but the data needs to be processed and placed in the database in real-time as it is received. A periodic task will miss records.

Comment: I have added the initialization code that shows the data being setup, received and logged.

Comment: Given that you don't show anything about the structure of your data nor anything about any model with which you may wish to store said data, then how are we to help you? I mean, the answer as it stands is use `SomeModel.create! data `.

Comment: Well, in fact, you probably use `RawData.create! rawdata: data`. Is there something more mysterious than that? How big is the `data`? Are you sure you're not going to truncate using `string`?

Comment: I’ve been trying to use RawData.create! In the process_raw method above, but apparently ‘RawData’ is undefined. Even tried requiring ‘active_record’ to no avail. Remember this is being set up in an initialization method and triggered as a callback from the gps gem. Is there something needed to enable access to the db from this environment?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured out what's missing. Seems in order to use models (such as 'RawData.create!') within an initializer the line

```
  RawData.connection
```

needs to be in the file. Once that is done, the database calls work as usual.

Thanks goes to jvillian for his help yesterday in getting me started in the right direction.